# train a language model with google ngrams

Tags: computational-linguistics, n-grams, language-models

I want to find a conditional probability of a word given its previous set of words. I plan to use `Google N-grams` for the same. However, being such a huge resource as it is, I don't think it is computationally possible to do on my PC. ( To process all N-grams, to train a language model).

So is there any way I can train a language model using Google Ngrams? (Even `python NLTK` library does not support `ngram` language model anymore)

Also is there any other way I can find a conditional probability of a word given the previous set of words ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has its focus on programming and estimating the size of a computer needed for a certain task. It is better asked on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score -1):

you can use Kullback–Leibler divergence.the paper Entropy-based Pruning of Backoff Language Models may can help you